# iOS 6 autorotation in simulator varies from actual iOS 6 device

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app will not autorotate in the iOS 6 GM simulator but it does with the same version of iOS on the device. Could this be a simulator bug? The app is using deprecated autorotation methods, but they are working fine on the device itself which makes me wonder if the simulator APIs are different?

Comment: Are you running the app compiled with iOS6 GM SDK?

Comment: That is a good question, how would I know? I am simply running the app on the device from within Xcode, on to a device running iOS 6, Using Xcode 4.5 which has the ios6 sdk and the iOS 6 simulator

Comment: Than it's the iOS6 SDK. I had run into the same problem, doing a small rewrite in my baseViewController I was able to add the new rotation methods, thus fixing it in the simulator. We have tested the before adding the new rotation code and it seemed to run just fine on a device.

Comment: did you add the new methods or replace the old ones or have them both in the viewcontroller at the same time? I wonder if I should be concerned that without the new methods the simulator does not work. If the device works, I suppose that is the main issue.

Comment: I've got them both in the viewcontroller. To keep them working in iOS 5

Comment: I attempted to add the two main new methods, `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` but they seemed to have no actual effect at all.

Comment: I've experienced another case of "deprecated method no longer works in iOS6 simulator simulator but still works on iOS6 device", this time about the deprecated grouped table view color (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406748/ios-6-autorotation-in-simulator-varies-from-actual-ios-6-device).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what I added to get my app working again:

```
// Tell the system what we support
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

// Tell the system It should autorotate
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

// Tell the system which initial orientation we want to have
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Where specifically did you add them? If I add them in my app delegate or my view controller it still doesn't work.

Comment: It's supposed to go in the `UIViewController`, you might have to tweak it a little bit.

Comment: Also be sure your Info.plist supports all the rotations you need.

Answer (score 15):

It should still work with the deprecated rotate methods, but you need to add the following to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
self.window.rootViewController = yourRootViewController;
```

This tells the main `window` what view controller to send the rotate notifications to. This is new with the iOS 6.0 SDK.

Comment: Wasn't that new in iOS5? I mean, they changed that in iOS5, or am I wrong?

Comment: It was new in iOS5, but you could seemingly safely ignore the deprecation warnings. In iOS6 you can't ignore them as it leads to the legacy rotation problem described. Have had exactly the same issue previously ...

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following was not enough to make it work on the simulator:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

To make it work, I also added the following inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function of the appDelegate class:

```
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

I stopped getting the following error after this addition:
***Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch***

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

and set the supported rotations for the root view controller in the app plist file to only portrait.