# XCode 4.5 iOS 6.0 simulator and rotation issues

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, uiinterfaceorientation, ios6

I have application made for iOS 4.2 and I was doing development in XCode 4.3.3 and testing it with iPhone 5.1 Simulator and everything worked fine. Recently I decided to test how application runs on iOS 6.0. When trying this, I face two problems:

1. So, I open application with XCode 4.5 and run it on iPhone 6.0 Simulator. I have problems oft with starting application. XCode just says: Finished running on iPhone 6.0 Simulator, stop button is grayed (like app is not running) and iPhone simulator just shows black screen and nothing happens. I have to CMD+Q it. And this is for me **HUGE problem**, since I manage to run application successfully randomly after lots of failures.
2. Eventually and sometimes, application runs without problems and I see that emulator is running my application. Application is made in landscape mode only. But when simulator runs application, it stays in portrait mode and shows application designed for landscape screen in portrait mode. I have set Supported Interface Orientations to both landscape variants and in Application-Info.plist are these two landscape orientations also listed.

Does anyone know what's happening and possible solution?

Many thanks in advance.

---

**[edit #1: Added All Output console message]**

Console message (for problem 1 which now keeps occurring) says:

```
error: failed to attach to process ID 0
```

---

**[edit #2: Small progress in solving 1st problem]**

Okay, strange things are happening. First thing I did in order to eliminate error from edit #1 was:

In XCode go to: **Product -> Edit Scheme -> Run [AppName].app -> Debugger and change it from LLDB to GDB**

After this, error from edit #1 is gone, **BUT** there's new problem. After I run application now I get status message in XCode: **Attaching to [AppName]** and XCode is stuck on that action.

If anyone gives me an answer, I want to say that I tried everything from the list below:

- **Go to Window -> Organizer -> Derived Data -> Delete**
- **Go to Window -> Organizer -> [ProjectName] and delete it completely
  and then reopen it**
- **Reset iPhone simulator settings**
- **Reset iPhone simulator + Clean Build + Quit Simulator + Run project**
- **Quit XCode + reboot Mac + reopen XCode and run application again**

and all kinds of these action permutations. Simply, I always see this problem. Best thing which happened to me was during this combination:

**Open only XCode without opening project -> Go to Window -> Organizer -> [ProjectName] and delete it completely -> Quit XCode -> Open iPhone simulator and reset settings -> Quit iPhone simulator -> reboot Mac -> reopen XCode and run application**

**Sometimes** in this case simulator managed to run my application right away, which is great. But after closing simulator and running application from XCode again (without doing anything between these two actions), XCode is stuck again on **Attaching to [AppName]** and won't start simulator with my application.

Although simulator won't start with my application from XCode, application itself is stored on simulator, and if I run simulator separately and start my application manually, application manages to start, but with 2nd problem I have in my problem description - layout issue.

---

**[edit #3: XCode version info]**

I forgot to mention my XCode version: **Xcode Version 4.5 (4G144l)**

---

**[edit #4: "Solution"]**

I found "solution" (I say "solution", since I haven't managed to find one in current XCode version).

I have just downloaded **XCode Version 4.5 (4G182)** and run my application normally (without changing Debugger to GDB) and everything's working fine except layout problem, which is definitely present because some changes made to iOS 6.0 comparing to iOS 5. I suppose this in fact is solution, since this version of XCode I used originally won't be used, since it was some of beta versions.

So, 1st problem is solved, still didn't manage to solve problem with layout.

---

**[edit #5: Final solution]**

Okay, 2nd problem solved. For all informations about my 2nd problem, here's the answer on this link: http://yusinto.blogspot.de/2012/08/ios-6-auto-rotate-and-orientation.html

Comment: iOS 6 is still under NDA, but try reading the whats new in iOS 6.0 section on the dev center

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 6 autorotation in simulator varies from actual iOS 6 device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406748/ios-6-autorotation-in-simulator-varies-from-actual-ios-6-device)

Comment: @rckoenes: My 2nd issue is description of (looks like) the same problem as question on link you gave and thanks for the link, but my 1st issue definitely is not duplicate of anything from that link.

Comment: @uerceg you are correct, sorry about that. I've not run into that problem my self, are you any warnings?

Comment: All warnings look fine and I had all of them in XCode 4.3.3 as well. Only this one is "stranger" than others: Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ApplcationName/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Application.app/some_icon.png

Comment: Close Xcode and restart your computer. Solved !

Comment: @Legolas, thanks for the tip, I tried that also and mentioned your method for solving in my edit #2. Please, have a look on updated question and if you have any suggestion, it'd be great. Many thanks for the tip once more.

Comment: see the answers i given here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448192/ios6-rotation-problems/13448914#13448914

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like I said in my edits, solution to my 1st problem was updating XCode to **Version 4.5 (4G182)**. Solution to my 2nd question was replacing deprecated iOS 5 method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

with 2 new methods introduced in iOS 6:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

After that, app works just fine.

**[edit #1: Adding working sample of landscape only app with iOS 5 and iOS 6 support]**

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController; 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
#pragma mark - Orientation support

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Comment: not setting a rootViewController can also cause this problem. 
Like if one uses [self.window addSubview:yourViewController.view]

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the `\Library\Application Support\iPhone Simulator` folder entirely and run simulator from XCode works for me.

Now I can run iOS 6.0 Simulator from XCode.