# ios6 rotation problems

Tags: ios6, screen-rotation

I am converting my app to ios6 but i am getting rotation problems.
Can some one help me which methods will be called when we rotate device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
    [self doLayoutForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation]; 
}


- (void)doLayoutForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation { 
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) 
{
//set the frames here
}
else 
{
//set the frames here
} 
}
```

These are the new methods in ios 6 where you can set the frames as per the orientation. Hope it will useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

`- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate`
`-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations`

These are the new functions added to iOS 6.

Comment: Are you using any third party UI framework like three20 or something?

Comment: I won't be able to answer to your problem without looking at the page's code on which the rotation is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
if([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||[self interfaceOrientation] ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
     //set the frames here
    }
    else if ([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||[self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
      //set the frames here
    }
}
```

better go with this , the above method will call every time when you change the orientation of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the rotation with these methods

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

If some-view in rotating and you don't want such as UIImagePickerController just make a child class and override first method.