# iOS deployment target 4.3, base sdk 6.0 not working on iOS 6 device

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

I have set my deployment **target to 4.3** and the **base SDK to 6.0** ***(as it comes with XCode 4.5)*** - when I run it on an **iOS 5.1 device**, everything works as expected, but as soon as I run it on an **iOS 6 device**, some problems come up. 
***E.g the views do not rotate anymore***. Why is this happening? (I am using the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method and I know that it is deprecated in **iOS 6**, but when the deployment target is set to **4.3** - this should not matter, correct?)

Answer (score 1):

It does matter, with iOS6 it's not as easy as before, where you could be quite safe during iOS updates.

Your code will run okay on devices running < iOS6

If the devices run >= iOS6.0 the new rotation handling will be used, so you have to adapt to this ...

Answer (score 1):

Check this post

[iOS 6 autorotation in simulator varies from actual iOS 6 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406748/ios-6-autorotation-in-simulator-varies-from-actual-ios-6-device)

The deployment target only indicates the lower iOS supported, you have to handle the new iOS 6 rotation